# How to fix my code, I want to add another column to it

Tags: sql, sybase

Basically, what is needed is to add a column next to `reclass to fund` with `fund name` which can be found in second column.

For example on `fundno 209674` with fund name `AB ALLL MARKET INC;C,` it has `reclass to fund` of 209672 and I need to put in the same row on `reclass to fundname` its corresponding fund name which is `AB ALL MARKET INC;A`

Looking for every solutions here but I can't seem to find anything. I'm trying any code I can but still can't get the desired result.

The fund names can only be found on the table fund, and to produce something on my desired column I need to extract it from the table fund and link it to the table reclassification_fund.

```
select
f.fundno,
f.fund_name,    
case
    when ((max(case when fa.attribute_type in ('RCLASS') then 
fa.attribute_type end)) is not null)
    then 'Y'
    else ' '
end as Reclassification,    
max(case when fa.attribute_type in ('RCLASS') then rf.reclass_to_fundno end) as Reclass_To_Fund,
max(case when fa.attribute_type in ('RCLASS') then rf.reclass_months end) as Reclass_Months

from 
fund f

join fund_attribute fa
on f.fundno = fa.fundno

left join reclassification_fund rf
on f.fundno = rf.fundno    

where f.fund_status_code='A' 

and f.category_code in(1,13,16,18,19,20,27,31)

group by
f.fundno,
f.fund_name,
f.fund_type,
f.fund_status_code,
f.category_code    

order by f.fund_name
```

My desired result is this:

[image: Desired Result]
But my current code only extracts this:

[image: Current Result]

With anything I do either the code does not work or it only returns fundnos with no "reclassification" attribute. The photo above is the my desired result, but remove the "reclass to fundname" and it is the result of my SQL Code.

Any kind of help would be really well appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results as *text tables* in the question would help.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question by showing, in addition to the SQL code, sample input data along with both the current and expected output.  A picture is worth a thousand words for SQL questions (but don't actually include any pictures).

Comment: Thanks! I already added the desired result and current result photo using this website's image upload tool. Apologies, as I don't know how to convert a table to text to be pasted here.